# Why do I get 2 instances when They are registered as singletons

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a class ClassA

```
public class ClassA : IRefreshable
{
}
```

and it is registered in the startup

```
services.AddSingleton<ClassA>();
```

I am also registering my services as a singleton

```
services.AddSingleton(services);
```

I have also created a controller named RefreshController which recieves the IServiceCollection in the constructor.

```
  public RefreshController(IServiceCollection sc)
  {
  }
```

now in the refresh controller I am using the service collection to fetch all types that are registered as singletons as implement IRefreshable so when calling Refresh end point I am iterating through them and using the service provider to get the instance

```
       this.typesToRefresh = sc.Where(s => s.Lifetime == ServiceLifetime.Singleton &&
       s.ServiceType.FullName.ToLower().StartsWith("MyNamespace")
       && typeof(IRefreshable).IsAssignableFrom(s.ImplementationType)).ToList();


            typesToRefresh.ForEach(t =>
            {
                IRefreshable rf = (IRefreshable)sProvider.GetService(t.ServiceType);
                rf.Refresh();
            });
```

My problem is that I get 2 instances for the same registered service. 
Any ideas??

Comment: Might need a more full example to help here. Where does `typesToRefresh` come from?

Comment: In what case would your service provider need to provide itself to something?

Comment: Are you sure it's two instances of the same service, not two distinct objects both cast to an `IRefreshable`?

Comment: @ChrisPickford 
The service collection is used to reflect which services are registered as singletons.
The service provider used to get the instances.

Comment: I don't get why you are adding the service collection as a service, why are you trying to use reflection here?

Comment: @ChrisPickford
2 instances with 2 passes through the class constructor and 2 different this.GetHashCode responses.
The instances are one created in the refresh and another one injected to a service.

Comment: @DavidG
I replied, I want to dynamically load all classes that are registered in the service collection and  implement IRefreshable and under my namespace.

Comment: Then why not do something like `public RefreshController(IEnumerable<IRefreshable> refreshables)`?

Comment: @DavidGThey are not added as IRefreshable so they wont be fetched as such.
The example shows that it is registered as the class name or a different more business related interface(abstraction)

Comment: Then add them as `IRefreshable`....?

Comment: @DavidG
That beats the all purpose of dynamically loading without registering.

Comment: But you're already registering.

Comment: as a different service, it will double the registration

Answer (score 0):

OK!
As it turns out each service provider is on it own.
I removed all .buildServiceProvider from my code and I am accessing the framework sp in the controller from the Httpcontext.RequestServices and in the Startup.Configure method in the IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.

Thanks for your help.